# Apache third level domain name configuration

Tags: apache, symfony, url-rewriting

i have specific rewrite like

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule .* /app_dev.php
```

and i need domain names like hello.epsilon.localhost and example.epsilon.localhost will go to epsilon.localhost virtualhost (sorry for my bad english)

full virtualhost for epsilon.localhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Projects/epsilon/web"

    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteRule .* /app_dev.php

<Directory "C:/Projects/epsilon/web">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

    ServerName epsilon.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

this rewrite for symfony 2.1

Comment: Add `ServerAlias` to VirtualHost configuration and add domain and subdomain to `hosts` file (`system32\hosts`).

Comment: i have added 
127.0.0.1 *.epsilon.localhost

Comment: and ServerAlias *.epsilon.localhost but i need third level name to be dynamic but it doesn't work

Comment: add rule to `.htaccess` file, if `HTTP_HOST` isn't equal `epsilon.localhost` rewrite to `epsilon.localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this http://sourceforge.net/projects/acrylic/ as a local DNS server on windows
and this in the Virtual host configuration

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
ServerName devsite.localhost
ServerAlias *.devsite.localhost

DocumentRoot "C:/httpdocs/devsite"
</VirtualHost>
```